# Hi i want to be able to copy and paste in a android paint application

Tags: android

hi i want to be able to add copy and paste function in a simple android paint application. I am not sure where to start as what is needed and where it should go. If anyone could advise it would be great.
Thanks to anyone who tries to help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are lots of way to do that, Here is what I could think of: 
1.Convert you view to SVG which is challenging because the view should be converted into path and etc. and the final result may not be the image that you want because there are some difficulties converting images to paths.
2.Convert your view to JPEG which is easier but it will copy every thing such as background shadows and you can only copy the whole view not just part of it , here is a code for that :

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/some/location/image.jpg"));
```

I couldnt find any library for the first solution.And it depends on your use case.
PS:You can create something like layers for photoshop and create a view for each shape and line but then there wil be lots of view and its not efficient.

Comment: i want to be able to add the picture to the android clipboard and paste pictures from more advanced paint applications into my more basic paint app.

Comment: @soper2005 Are you sure that other apps copy button, copies the image to clipboard as well? I mean does your your phones clipboard shows the copied image ?